# Apache: possible to define a script outside the webroot as the start page?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

In httpd.conf I defined a virtual host like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myproject
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject/www"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I would like a script *outside* the `www` folder to be the startpoint of this website.

The script I want to run first is : `C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject/build.php` , which then starts doing some work (copying stuff, generating cache, etc.) and then redirects to `index.php` in the `www` folder (using a `header("location: ...")` in PHP).

Is this possible?

***UPDATE***

This works (put inside VirtualHost) :

```
Alias /index.php "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject/build.php"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

You can put the root anywhere you want - "DocumentRoot" does *not* need to be under www.

You can put any other directory in any different physical location you want - just use the `<Alias>` directive:

http://www.thewebhostinghero.com/tutorials/apache-alias.html

Comment: yes but I do want the DocumentRoot to be www ! The whole page uses this root, but I just want the first page (index.php or index.html) to be from somewhere else...

Comment: thanx ,  alias does work !  I defined it as   Alias /index.php "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject/build.php"